# how to get the url only in javascript shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify

I have a metafield of type `document`, and in the ajax query I get the value of this field as

```
"gid://shopify/GenericFile/31146481287411"
```

I need the url. I can easily get that url in liquid using `file_url`:

```
{{ metafields.custom.document | file_url }}
```

But I need to get the url specifically in javascript!

Please tell me how I can do this, and is there a workaround?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the file url in a string metafield, and get that instead of the GID to a resource. Alternatively, since your JS has to run AFTER Liquid rendering, render the URL into a JS variable and use it as you wish. You have plenty of options.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I've already done. Thanks